# Arduino data value from button increments instead of high/low

Tags: arduino

I have also posted this question [here](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=554806.0).

I am connecting to a MUX74HC4067 and reading the value of each pin. All the values keep increment together until reaching 227 then it starts over. I am unsure what is wrong I am setting the pins later as I will eventually retrieve these from a ini file to configure the board when it is all working correctly.

The serial monitor is outputting the following as a short example:

```
Push button at channel 0 is 197
Push button at channel 1 is 197
Push button at channel 2 is 197
Push button at channel 3 is 197
Push button at channel 4 is 197
Push button at channel 5 is 197
Push button at channel 6 is 197
Push button at channel 7 is 197
Push button at channel 8 is 197
Push button at channel 9 is 197
Push button at channel 10 is 197
Push button at channel 11 is 197
Push button at channel 12 is 197
Push button at channel 13 is 197
Push button at channel 14 is 197
Push button at channel 15 is 197

Push button at channel 0 is 227
Push button at channel 1 is 227
Push button at channel 2 is 227
Push button at channel 3 is 227
Push button at channel 4 is 227
Push button at channel 5 is 227
Push button at channel 6 is 227
Push button at channel 7 is 227
Push button at channel 8 is 227
Push button at channel 9 is 227
Push button at channel 10 is 227
Push button at channel 11 is 227
Push button at channel 12 is 227
Push button at channel 13 is 227
Push button at channel 14 is 227
Push button at channel 15 is 227
```

```cpp
#include "MUX74HC4067.h"

// Creates a MUX74HC4067 instance
// 1st argument is the Arduino PIN to which the EN pin connects
// 2nd-5th arguments are the Arduino PINs to which the S0-S3 pins connect

MUX74HC4067 *pmux1 = NULL;

void setup()
{
MUX74HC4067 pmux1(22,23,24,25,26);

Serial.begin(9600);  // Initializes serial port
 // Waits for serial port to connect. Needed for Leonardo only
while ( !Serial ) ;

// Configures how the SIG pin will be interfaced
// e.g. The SIG pin connects to PIN 3 on the Arduino,
//      and PIN 3 is a digital input
//  mux1.signalPin(27, INPUT, DIGITAL);
 pmux1.signalPin(27, INPUT, DIGITAL);
}

// Reads the 16 channels and reports on the serial monitor
// if the corresponding push button is pressed
void loop()
{
 byte data;

for (byte i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
{
    // Reads from channel i and returns HIGH or LOW
data = pmux1->read(i);


    Serial.print("Push button at channel ");
    Serial.print(i);
    Serial.print(" is ");
   Serial.println(data);
    if ( data == HIGH ) Serial.println("not pressed");
    else if ( data == LOW ) Serial.println("pressed");
}
Serial.println();

delay(1500);
}
```

This is the link to the [library mux](https://github.com/pAIgn10/MUX74HC4067).

This line of code retrieves the value and in the tutorial:

```
 data = mux1.read(i);
```

and works ok.

I changed to below as the pins will be set from an INI file when all working.

```
data = pmux1->read(i);
```

I am at a loss as too retrieve the values so they are HIGH or LOW.